# MariaDB MATCH AGAINST with single quote search term?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to find a working query for using MATCH AGAINST while having a search term containing a single quote.

Example data in the database table:

```
I'm a freak
```

Example search term:

```
I'm
```

Search queries I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"I\'m"' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"I\'m"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('I\'m*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('(I\'m)*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

...and many more. Nothing is working.

I'm using MariaDB 10.1.33.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with a double apostrophe `I''M`. Are you sure it's a real apostrophe and not one of those fancy curly ones with a different character code?

Comment: @Jacob H: Yes, it's a real one. ;) And thanks for the suggestion, but double apostrophes don't work either. :(

Comment: Is it an InnoDB or a MyISAM table?

Comment: @stickybit InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

- I'm pretty sure contractions are not treated as words.
- Instead the apostrophe is treated as a word separator giving you "I" and "m".
- But you probably don't have `innodb_ft_min_token_size=1`, so those two "words" are ignored.

There are limitations of FT; you have encountered one of them.